# What is the meaning of "No" in this line of code [VBA]

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA programming and recently I have come accross this line of code at work and I couldn't find any answer for it from my colleagues, as none of them are coders.

```
S2_path = "\\wswvnascti0005\fin_pol_pcRegion\MENA\S2_reports\"
S2_file = "CEEMEA-StandardPLCEEMEA_with_daily-20" & year & month & day & ".csv"
folder_to = "\\wswvnascti0005\fin_pol_pcRegion\MENA\ALL\"
pnl_new = "MENA_Consolidated_PnL_20" & year & "-" & month & "-" & day & ".xlsm"

Application.Workbooks.Open S2_path & S2_file, No
```

The line of code that I'm talking about is the last line, where you can find the word ***No***. What is the meaning of that word in this case?

Thanks for help guys and sorry for my English!

Comment: it's referes to the second parameter of the `Workbooks.Open` command, which is `UpdateLinks`. If you want to update the links when you open the workbook (or not), the value should be `0` (for No) or `3` (for Yes), not `No`. One last thing, if you are running this code from Excel, you can drop the `Application`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's (incorrectly) saying not to update links (`UpdateLinks`) - should say `False` here.
The parameters as delineated by commas (as per below) and because it's after the first comma, it's related to `UpdateLinks`.

Another way that code could have been written would be `Application.Workbooks.Open S2_path & S2_file, UpdateLinks:=False`

[image]

Comment: @AfrikaKorps no worries - if your question has been answered, a "Best answer" mark would do nicely ;)

Comment: @AfrikaKorps also, I only spotted now that the "no" is incorrect (I assume they were trying to not to updated links) so see my updated answer above